# Issues regarding angularjs + requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Trying to implement modular loading using requirejs into angularjs. Having a hard time to understand requirejs and its config options. Here's what i have so far. My questions are below

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="app/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="app/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script data-main="app/main.js" src="app/vendor/require/require-2.1.11.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div ng-include="flexyLayout('header')"></div>
        <div ng-view id="content"></div>
        <div ng-include="flexyLayout('footer')"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'angular': 'vendor/angular/angular.min',
        'angular-route': 'vendor/angular/angular-route.min',
        'angular-cookies': 'vendor/angular/angular-cookies.min'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-route' : {
            exports : 'angular',
            deps : ['angular']
        },
        'angular-cookies' : {
           deps : ['angular']
        }
    }
});

require(
    [
        'angular',
        'app',
        'module/login/login',
        'services/services'
    ],
    function(angular, app) {
        'use strict';
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
```

app.js

```
define(['angular', 'angular-route'], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/module/public/index.html',
                header: 'app/partials/header.html',
                footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'app/module/login/login.html',
                header: 'app/partials/header.html',
                footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
            })
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'app/module/home/home.html',
                header: 'app/partials/header.html',
                footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
            })
            .when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'app/module/register/register.html',
                header: 'app/partials/header.html',
                footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
            })
            .when('/admin', {
                templateUrl: 'app/module/admin/admin.html',
                header: 'app/partials/header.html',
                footer: 'app/partials/footer.html',
                permission: 'admin'
            })
            .when('/unauthorized', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/unauthorized.html',
                header: 'app/partials/header.html',
                footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });

    return app;
});
```

login.js

```
define(['app','services/services'], function (app) {
    app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,AuthenticatorService,CookieService,$window,$location) {
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.login = function() {
            AuthenticatorService.authenticate($scope.user).then(function(response){
                if(response.authentication) {
                    CookieService.saveLoginData(response.user);
                    $window.location.href = $location.absUrl()+'home';
                }else {
                    $scope.error = response.message;
                    $scope.user = {};
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Questions:

1. The angularjs cookies file isn't loading up due to which i am getting unknown provider error. When i inspect the element, i can see angularjs and angular-route js files loaded but not angularjs cookies file. Is the setting in `shim` option incorrect for `angular-cookies`?
2. How to load services and directives? My `services.js` file is inside the `services` folder. Am i loading it the correct way by calling it in `require`? Can i load services.js file in the `paths` option of the `require.config`?
3. I read through some of the posts here but did not clearly understand how to use requirejs to load modular file. Example, i have different modules like login , admin, register etc. How do i load the individual module js files using requirejs. Below is my root folder structure

[image: My App root directory structure]

I would appreciate if anyone could explain me with code. If you need any other detail plz let me know and sorry for such a long post. Couldn't explain it in brief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *angularjs cookies file isn't loading*: You have to require it from someplace (or use the `deps` configuration option from `require.config()`). Providing a shim for it does *not* automatically require it.
2. Loading `services.js` as `define([...,'services/services'],...)` seems OK. Does it not load? Are you having any other problems?

   On the other hand, the `paths` configuration is a means to provide aliases (so to speak). Like `shim`, it does not auto-load stuff.
3. To load the individual modules, you will have to require them from someplace. With Angular, this may lead to awkward situations like:

   ```
   define(["module1","module2","module3",...,"module1024"], function() {
       // do nothing but load all the modules
   });
   ```

I am trying myself to combine AngularJS + RequireJS + the optimizer (see [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) and [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy)). The angular-require-lazy project is far from beign complete, but it may give you some ideas. (I am about to make some major changes to it, fighting some bugs now, but the general idea will remain.)

Also as a sidenote: Maybe you should pause a bit and familiarize yourself with Require, with a small test project or something...